# php how to find exect word in php string

Tags: php, string

I want to find the exact value in the title, here is my code

```
 $title ="Get 25% Off in my title";

    $findme   = array("5% Off","10% off","15% Off","20% Off","25% Off","30% Off","35% Off","40% Off","45% Off","50% Off","55% Off","60% Off","65% Off","70% Off","75% Off","80% Off","$5 Off","$10 Off","$15 Off","$20 Off","$25 Off","$30 Off","$35 Off","$40 Off","$45 Off");

  $array_with_lcvalues = array_map('strtolower',$findme);

    $mystring = strtolower($title);
    foreach($array_with_lcvalues as $match){
       if (strpos($mystring,$match) !== false) {
             echo  $match ;
            } 
        }
```

I need to know how to find the exact value as I am getting 2 values. Wheras the exact value for this code should be 25%.

The output of the code is 
5% off
25% off

Comment: You asked for % only in your question, please ask everything when you write a question. We are giving answer according to your question. thanks for unmarked. I am going to delete this answer after sometime. –

Answer (score 0):

use regex:

```
preg_match_all('/(\d+)%\s*off/i', $title, $matches);
```

heres the [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/S3dUe) code.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `preg_match` with `\b` which is a word bound and `/i` making it case insensitive.

```
<?php

$title ="Get 25% Off in my title";

$findme   = array("5% Off","10% off","15% Off","20% Off","25% Off","30% Off","35% Off","40% Off","45% Off","50% Off","55% Off","60% Off","65% Off","70% Off","75% Off","80% Off","$5 Off","$10 Off","$15 Off","$20 Off","$25 Off","$30 Off","$35 Off","$40 Off","$45 Off");

preg_match("/\b(" . implode($findme,"|") . ")\b/i", $title, $matches);

print_r($matches);

?>
```